# Accessing instance variable causing retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

If I have:

```
@interface SomeClass() {
    NSObject *_someObject;
}

...

- (void)someMethod {
    [self doSomething:^(NSObject *someOtherObject) {
          _someObject = someOtherObject;
    }];
}
...
```

Will there by a retain cycle with self since we accessed _someObject within that block?

Comment: As long as the block isn't being retained by "self", then no.

Comment: We really need to see what doSomething: is doing.

Comment: Use a property. Simple.

Comment: @Fogmeister How does using a property change the answer?

Answer (score 4):

in this case, self will be retained, if you access to class variable like here, it the same like:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [self doSomething:^(NSObject *someOtherObject) {
          self->_someObject = someOtherObject;
    }];
}
```

if created block will be destroyed before self, everything will be ok, but if block live longer then all other references to self, self will stay in memory, while block will not release it.

I recommend to use this one code:

```
@interface SomeClass()     

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSObject *someObject;

...

- (void)someMethod {
    __weak SomeClass *weak_self = self;
    [self doSomething:^(NSObject *someOtherObject) {
          weak_self.someObject = someOtherObject;
    }];
}
...
```

or

```
@interface SomeClass() {
    NSObject *_someObject;
}

...

- (void)someMethod {
    __weak SomeClass *weak_self = self;
    [self doSomething:^(NSObject *someOtherObject) {
          __strong SomeClass *strong_self = weak_self;
          strong_self->_someObject = someOtherObject;
    }];
}
...
```

Comment: Does your weak_self even lift? Bro?